# DBContext save changes using IAsyncActionFilter and awaiting full completion

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am a bit stuck/confused.  I am trying to write an API using .Net6 that has a save function which saves some header information (header table) and details (detail table). The relationship is there is one header row but it will have multiple detail rows (one-to-many).  I am having to use entity framework 3 for this.  I can get it to save etc using the following code:

```
var entry = await dbContext.Header.AddAsync(headerInfo).ConfigureAwait(false);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

details.Id = entry.Entity.Id 
(updates details id to be the next one from the auto incremented column in the db)

await dbContext.Details.AddAsync(details).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

`headerInfo` and details represents the two class I'm trying to save.

However I am going to have multiple different Saves later on in the project - I was trying to experiment with `IAsyncActionFilter` to be able to wrap up the following:

1. beginning of a transaction
2. perform the generic update (in this case its the save of the header)
3. perform the `saveChangesAsync` method()
4. return back with the up updated Id to be used in assigning to the detail.

Below is snippets of code I'm currently using:

Filter - `OnActionExecutionAsync`

```
IDbContextTransaction transaction = await dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
await next().ConfigureAwait(false);
await.dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(new CancellationToken()).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Startup

```
 services.Configure<MvcOptions>(o => {
   o.Filters.Add<Filter<DbContext>>();
 });
```

What appears to be happening is the

```
dbContext.Header.AddAsync(headerInfo).ConfigureAwait(false)
```

is returning before the `SaveChangesAsync()` is called.

So I suppose my questions are:

1. Is this possible
2. If so what am I missing
3. Or have I got my entity models wrong. (I can post more if needed)

I've been looking at this for a while so I'm not sure if I've just gotten snow blind at this stage.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *is returning before the SaveChangesAsync() is called* -- Isn't that supposed to be happening? After all, you await `AddAsync`. Apart from that, two things to note: 1. you probably don't need `AddAsync`, just use `Add`. 2. Use navigation properties to build `Header` and their `Detail`s, then call `SaveChangesAsync` once.

Comment: @GertArnold sorry want to make sure we are both on the same page.  I thought by await my first save header on the dbContext that i would end up awaiting the filter execution as well. But that appears not to be the case - it basically returns to the calling code" after the await BeginTransaction.

Comment: `AddAsync` doesn't add anything to the database. `Add` starts tracking a new object in the `Added` state so doesn't need asynchronous execution. As the docs explain `AddAsync` is *only* used for special PK strategies like HiLo that need to retrieve a range of IDs from the server. It's `SaveChanges` that persists all pending changes to the database. SaveChanges is *only* meant to be called at the very end, to commit all pending changes. DbContext is a Unit-of-Work and detects all the changes made to the objects it tracks.

Comment: `updates details id to be the next one` you don't have to, EF Core will do it automatically. In fact, if `Header` contains 10 details, `Add(header)` will start tracking both Header and all 10 Details in the `Added` state. By calling `SaveChanges` at the start you broke this functionality

Comment: Finally `dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync` not only is this *completely* unnecessary, it's a major bug that breaks EF's transaction logic. Remove all manual transaction attempts and use DbContext as the Unit-of-Work/Transaction. Make any changes you want *in memory* and then either call `SaveChanges` to persist all of them in a single internal DB transaction, or dispose the DbContext, thus discarding all changes

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be a bit confused about what `await` and `async` operations are doing, and possibly the effects of `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

`await`-ed Asynchronous methods do not parallelize operations, in actuality they de-parallelize them, or prevent them from parallelizing as a DbContext is not thread safe. We wouldn't want code trying to use a DbContext in two separate worker threads at the same time.

We want to support asynchronous operations so that the current worker thread can be suspended and the controlling process can free up threads for handling other work, such as ASP.Net responding to other requests while a background worker has EF busy fetching data. `await` ensures that the caller resumes only after that call comes back. `ConfigureAwait(false)` simply tells it that it does not need to schedule resuming in the same synchronization context as the original request. (I.e. go back to a UI thread) AFAIK with ASP.Net Core using `ConfigureAwait(false)` isn't really needed as it does not use an explicit synchronization context, but don't quote me on that. :) It's more for desktop applications where you may want to await operations and know that you aren't going to need to go back to the UI thread or will marshal that explicitly. (I.e. only going to the UI in the event of an error)

Now looking at your example:

```
var entry = await dbContext.Header.AddAsync(headerInfo).ConfigureAwait(false);
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

details.Id = entry.Entity.Id 
(updates details id to be the next one from the auto incremented column in the db)

await dbContext.Details.AddAsync(details).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This is an outdated pattern common to typical ADO-era data access. Create a Header, save it, get it's ID, create a Detail and set it's Header ID, save it... Wrap the whole thing in a transaction so if the Detail save fails, the Header can be rolled back.

With EF this type of logic/construct is not necessary. You use navigation properties for related entities. For instance a Detail entity would have a reference to it's applicable Header. If we want to create a new Detail with a new Header we would do the following:

```
var header = new Header { /* set details */ };
var detail = new Detail { /* set details */, Header = header };
context.Details.Add(detail);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

EF manages FK associations and automatically wraps all operations within a transaction. It will not insert a header if the detail fails, and based on the relationship configured for the navigation property it knows automatically that the Header will need to be inserted first, followed by the Detail, and it automatically provides the Detail with the HeaderId where Header's PK is something like an Identity column. (Auto-increment, or Guid with a default of NewId()/NewSequentialId())

Comment: It should be stressed that no call to` BeginTransaction` is needed. That's where the OP's problem started